# Wiring List[T <: Foo] to subclass of Foo in a typesafe way

Tags: scala

```
class Foo {}

class Bar[T <: Foo] {
    var items : List[T] = Nil
    def add(i: T) = items ::= i
}

class Fog extends Foo {
    def add(bar: Bar[this.type]) = bar.add(this)
}

object Test {
    val bag = new Bar[Fog]
    val fog = new Fog
    fog.add(bag)
}
```

The compiler barks with:

```
Error:(20, 13) type mismatch;
 found   : Bar[rules.Fog]
 required: Bar[rules.Test.fog.type]
Note: Fog >: Test.fog.type, but class Bar is invariant in type T.
You may wish to define T as -T instead. (SLS 4.5)
    fog.add(bag)
            ^
```

However, chaning T to -T yields:

```
Error:(9, 9) contravariant type T occurs in covariant position in type => List[T] of method items
    var items : List[T] = Nil
        ^
```

What I want to achieve is that  adds itself in a typesafe way to a Bar[Fog].

Comment: def add(bar: Bar[Fog]) = bar.add(this)

Comment: The question is, when you extend `Fog` to `Fox`, what do you want `Fox.add` to accept? `Bar[Fog]` or `Bar[Fox]`? Your code implies the latter, but it's impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Your code implies that you want to subclass `Fog`, do you?

If not you can do this:

```
final class Fog extends Foo {
  def add(bar: Bar[Fog]) = bar.add(this)
}
```

If yes, than you will have to re-arrange your code a bit because add expects a bag of any implementation of `Fog` (e.g. a subclass or `new Fog with Mixin`):

```
class Foo {}

class Bar[T <: Foo] {
  var items : List[T] = Nil
  def add(i: T) = items ::= i
}

class Fog extends Foo {
  def add(bar: Bar[this.type]) = bar.add(this)
}

trait Mixin {
   def crazy = true
}

object Test {
  val fog = new Fog with Mixin
  // you need to tell Bar what fog actually is
  val bag = new Bar[fog.type]
  fog.add(bag)
}
```

**EDIT:**

However, that would mean you can only ever add the exact type you define for `Bar` to your `bag`.

Depending on your needs you can also make `T` in `Bar` *contra-variant*, then you could add different sub-types of `Fog` to your bag:

```
class Foo {}

class Bar[-T <: Foo] {
  var items : List[Foo] = Nil
  def add[A <: T] (i: A) = items ::= i
}

class Fog extends Foo {
  def add(bar: Bar[Fog]) = bar.add(this)
}

trait Mixin {
  def crazy = true
}

val fog = new Fog with Mixin
// you need to tell Bar what fog actually is
val bag = new Bar[Fog]
fog.add(bag)
(new Fog).add(bag)

// when accessing items you would have to type match, though
val test1 = bag.items.map {
  case f : Fog with Mixin => 1
  case f : Fog => 2
  case f : Foo => 3
}

// Result: List(2, 1)
```

Comment: Is there a way to get "var items : List[Foo] = Nil" typesafe?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by **type safe**? You can make it invariant, then you can almost always (there may still be cases of erasure) be sure of they type in the list. But then it is invariant. If you want to be able to add different subclasses of Fog to the same container ending up with a List(SomeFog, SomeFogWithMixin, SomeFogSubclass), then the only thing you can be sure about is that it what you get is a subclass of Foo.

Comment: What I want to achieve is a compile-time typecheck when calling "add" on a concrete subclass of "Fog" that the passed Bar[] is typed with a Fog or some superclass of Fog. However, I understand that actually Bar has to be Bar[+T] because it's a container and that way the compile-time check cannot be done. So, I need to do a runtime check...

Comment: A little more of compile-time typecheck could be achieved by defining add[T](bar: Bar[T]) in Fog and then refining it to add[X] in any subclass X of Fog.